# mysql PHP row count + percentage

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table:

```
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `clothes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shirt` text NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
-- ----------------------------
```

Sample table content:

```
id shirt color
1  long  white
2  short yellow
3  long  blue
4  long  blue
5  long  white
6  short white
7  short white
8  long  yellow
9  long  yellow
10 short yellow
```

My FINAL GOAL is to feed the results into this format:

```
<ul>
<li>Total Rows: <?php echo $totalRows; ?></li>

<li>total yellow count:   <?php echo $yellowCount; ?></li>
<li>total yellow percent: <?php echo $yellowPercentage; ?></li>

<li>total blue count:    <?php echo $blueCount; ?></li>
<li>total blue percent:  <?php echo $bluePercentage; ?></li>

<li>total white count:    <?php echo $whiteCount; ?></li>
<li>total white percent:  <?php echo $whitePercentage; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Resulting in (with rounded percentages):

```
  <ul>
    <li>Total Rows: 10 </li>

    <li>total yellow count:  4</li>
    <li>total yellow percent: 40%</li>

    <li>total blue count:    2</li>
    <li>total blue percent:  20%</li>

    <li>total white count:    4</li>
    <li>total white percent:  40%</li>
    </ul>
```

I've been experimenting with various code but nothing has gotten me where I need to be:

```
 <?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);

   // Make a MySQL Connection

$query = "SELECT color, COUNT(color) FROM clothes GROUP BY color"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(color)'] ." ". $row['color'] ." items.";
    echo "<br />";
}

    ?>
```

That gets me almost there with this -- but I need to be able to separate the results for inserting into HTML:

```
There are 4 white items.
There are 4 yellow items.
There are 2 blue items.
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. THANKS.

Comment: At least finish writing your queries and try them out... see what happens. Once you see the result, then you can perhaps figure out where you're going wrong. You're on the right track with COUNT - you'll also need to use WHERE clauses to separate out the counts per colour.

Comment: You hadn't even provided a runnable sample at the time. If people just give you the answer for no effort, you don't learn anything. At the very least, when you come here you should have something compiled and tried before you start asking for help. That way you get the experience of going through the try / fail / debug sequence first - believe me, you'll learn so much more. As Rohan said below - you need to put in some effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you could do:

```
SELECT color, COUNT(*) AS color_count FROM clothes GROUP BY color
```

You should get a result like:

```
color    color_count
yellow   7
red      1
white    9
```

This data should be enough for you to compute the total number of rows (a sum of all the `color_count` values) and their percentage (just divide them).

So, in php you'll have something like:

```
$query = "SELECT color, COUNT(*) AS color_count FROM clothes GROUP BY color";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$values = array();
$pct = array();
$total = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $values[$row["color"]] = $row["color_count"];
    $total += $row["color_count"];
}

foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $pct[$key] = $value/$total;
}
```

So, in the end what you have is, `$values["yellow"]` will give you the number of yellow clothes, and `$pct["yellow"]*100` will give you the percentage of clothes that is yellow.

Comment: I just gave this a try and a parse error:                          Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS, expecting ';'        for($values as $key => $value) {
    $pct[$key] = $value/$total;
}

Comment: My bad.. change the for to foreach.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rohan, but correcting the foreach now results in no output :)

Comment: You honestly need to re-read the question and put in some effort from your side. The above script produces NO OUTPUT but gives you variables to do exactly what you want. I have anyways done a lot of your work, don't expect me to write the entire thing for you.

Comment: Hey - I appreciate your help -- I had missed the bit about the $values["color"] output.